# Can't make request to localhost subdomain in getServerSideProps() of nextjs application running in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, reverse-proxy, server-side-rendering

I’m running my nextjs application inside of a docker container. Inside of this nextjs application I’m communicating with an API that is also hosted inside of its own docker container. Both of these are connected to the same docker network (nginx-proxy). To this nginx-proxy network is connected also a nginx-proxy container that takes care of proxying the request from domain to particular docker container.

In my production environment there is no problem however on localhost there is. My nextjs application is running on `admin.bengr.localhost` and the api is running on `api.bengr.localhost`.
When I try to make a request from my nextjs application client side to http://api.bengr.localhost it works. However when I try to make a request to this address from **getServerSideProps()** it throws this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.bengr.localhost
```

This is how my docker-compose.yml for my nextjs application looks:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=admin.bengr.localhost
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=admin.bengr.localhost

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nginx-proxy
```

This is how my **getServerSideProps()** function looks:

```
const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({params, req, res }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://api.bengr.localhost/admin/builder/pages', {
      params: {
        url: getRoute(params),
      }
    })
  } catch(err: any) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

I have tried to add `api.bengr.localhost` into `/etc/hosts` file like so:

```
127.0.0.1       api.bengr.localhost
```

However then I was getting this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```